# Transmission in snow leopard slow/torrent not starting

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, performance, transmission

after installing snow leopard transmission has become very to start downloading or to start seeding. when i add a torrent with lots of seeders the torrent does not start downloading imidietly like it should, it takes normaly about 5-10 minuttes or it doesnt start at all.

And in utorrent everythings starts fine and download/upload speeds are good.

these are the things I have checked:
*ports are open
*no speedlimits are set.
*Tried the newst stable version and the beta version

I was wondering if anynone else has the same problem or if anyone has a solution to the problem.

Comment: I don't recommend using transmission on Mac yet,it's not that stable to be used in day-to-day operations

Comment: You need to use the clutch, otherwise you might stall it.

Answer (score 2):

On the Tranmission bug/changes tracking site I found....

Transmission 1.75 beta 2 (2009/09/08) ¶

All tickets closed by this release
All Platforms ¶

```
* Don't wait so long on unresponsive trackers if there are other trackers to try
```

Mac ¶

```
* Fix libcurl build issue that caused tracker connectivity problems on Snow Leopard
```

Likely that you are seeing the results of a combination of unresponsive trackers and tracker connectivity. Will be fixed in next GA is my guess.